# enctype="multipart/form-data" Encoding error

Tags: html

Good afternoon mates, I have a problem with my form, because apart from my input type=file, i have other text inputs, and after adding that enctype attribute, names like "Gijón" turns to "GijÃ³n".

```
<form action="test.jsp" class="formular form form-horizontal well row" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="idFormUserReg" name="form1" novalidate>
        <div class="row" >
            <p class="span5" >
                <label for="idShortCompanyName">Short Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="shortName"  id="idShortName" maxlength="30" class="input-large" value="<%=aShortCompanyName%>">
            </p>
            <p class="span5" >
                <label for="idNameLogo">Logo</label>
                <input type="file" name="logoFile" id="idNameLogo">
                <input type="hidden" name="nameLogo" value="logo_<%=lIdClient%>.png">
            </p>
        </div>
</form
```

Can you guys know any way to keep a unique form from both inputs, but getting a right encoding? Thanks!

Comment: Does your applicant support UTF-8?

Comment: Ehm... I guess so, I don't get what you're trying to say

Comment: `GijÃ³n` is UTF-8 misrendered as some single-byte encoding (e.g. Latin-1 or Windows-1252). If your application supports UTF-8, then such input is correct and you're doing something wrong afterwards. If it doesn't, then the input is invalid and you're possibly failing to tell the browser what encoding to use.

Comment: Buenas Álvaro, puedo hablarte en español? Como le puedo decir al navegador qué codificación usar? Prové con enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8", así los input type=text van bién, pero el file no se guarda. Qué otra forma puede haber?

Comment: Well, this is an English speaking site :) If you expect UTF-8 and receive UTF-8 then nothing needs fixing on that regard. What do you mean with file not being saved? If you are trying to create a file on disk with accented names, that's an entirely different issue.

Comment: I mean, I have two Java Files, and I'm passing all the input values from one to the other, so when I recieve them, this happens. First Java = "Gijón", second Java = "GijÃ³n", I just need to get what it is in my first Java, I don't get why it changes.

Comment: GijÃ³n is UTF-8 misrendered as some single-byte encoding (e.g. Latin-1 or Windows-1252). So how can I turn back to UTF-8?